# Get context inside onClick(DialogInterface v, int buttonId)?

Tags: android, dialog, onclick, android-context

Getting the context inside `onClick(View view)`, the callback for a button's `onClickListener()`, is easy:

```
view.getContext()
```

But I can't figure out how to get the context inside `onClick(DialogInterface v, int buttonId)`, the callback for a **dialog**'s `onClickListener`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please answer this for Kotlin too!

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can reference an outer context when you define your `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` as an anonymous class. If you're in an activity you can use `MyActivity.this` as the context.

**Edit** - since your Activity is implementing `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`, you should be able to just use `this` as the context.

Comment: 'this' works very well. I have no idea why I couldn't figure this out myself.

Comment: Tu Sum Up, use `MyActivity.this`

Answer (score 19):

If your DialogInterface is within MainActivity, then you can get the context using

```
MainActivity.this.getActivityContext();
```

Btw You can also implement the DialogInterface (in your code sample, you have written implements twice) and the same statement can be used to get the activity context.

Answer (score 16):

Here is how you do it in case you

1. do not want to have any anonymous class usage
2. or having your activity/fragment implement the interface directly.

Just simply,

1. use `dialogInterface` object and cast it to `Dialog` object
2. then call `getContext()`

Example with [DialogInterface.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html):

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener foo = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
        Dialog dialog  = (Dialog) dialogInterface;
        Context context = dialog.getContext();
        // do some work with context
    }
};
```

This will also work for the following interfaces as well, just use the first param `DialogInterface dialogInterface` and cast.

- [DialogInterface.OnCancelListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnCancelListener.html)
- [DialogInterface.OnDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html)
- [DialogInterface.OnKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnKeyListener.html)
- [DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener.html)
- [DialogInterface.OnShowListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnShowListener.html)

Comment: The fact that you can cast the `DialogInterface` is harder to find than one would think. Saved me a lot of time there.

Comment: @petey Did this solution to retrieve context always work? If yes it would be a great way to finally retrieve it in this common case.

Comment: @YoannHercouet  yea,  it will work when used in any methods for a DialogInterface

Comment: @petey Great then! That will prevent the random NPE that I was sometimes getting using `getActivity()`...

Comment: yea...`getActivity()` can be unfun at times.

Answer (score 0):

inside setOnClickListener

decelare this below the class

`Context context = this;`

and use this context

`AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);`

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin, You can use below text.

**this@MainActivity**