# Android AlertDialog and PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, preferences

I created a PreferenceActivity with a Custom Title. In the title I added a button. In the button click event I added:

```
imageClearCache.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) { 
....


    new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                      .setTitle("Alert!!")
                      .setMessage("Text...")
                      .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                                // continue with delete
                            }
                         }).show();
    }
```

I get the error: ...Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Any idea?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the normal context (in this case your activity) provided by the view being clicked instead of the application context.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
```

Comment: There is no view in my case. What do I do?

Comment: @bluemunch see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447092/get-context-inside-onclickdialoginterface-v-int-buttonid/22049950#22049950