# Alert Dialogue box on image view click listener in android

Tags: android, dialog, imageview, android-alertdialog

I am working on android application in which i want to make a selection dialog box on my imageView click listener. Without dialog box it is working fine, but when i add dialog box with list in it it shows exception. My code and error stack is given below:

```
profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               //@Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ImageClicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     

                   final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
                   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                   builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
                   builder.setCancelable(false);
                 //  builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_action_dismiss, null);

                   // creating a single choice item menu (radio buttons list)
                   // -1 indicates that no item should be selected by default
                   // pass index argument starting from 0 to preselect an item if required
                   builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                   });

                   AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                   alert.show();

               }        
            });

11-25 20:03:02.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17343): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
11-25 20:03:02.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17343):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:650)
11-25 20:03:02.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17343):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
11-25 20:03:02.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17343):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
11-25 20:03:02.625: E/AndroidRuntime(17343):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
```

Comment: This is answer to your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `getApplicationContext()` to `v.getContext()`

Comment: also,  this answer will help you get a valid context from a `DialogInterface`, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22049950/794088

Comment: thanks for your reply. It works. But it locks my screen, like when i press back button or if i press any point on the screen nothing happens and it will not allow me to go back on the screen.

Comment: does it still do this if you use `builder.setCancelable(true);`

Comment: where should i use it in my code? I mean on which portion?

Comment: where you have `builder.setCancelable(false);`,  change it to true.