# How do I get Activity Context inside DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick()?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-context

I was looking at this question:

> [How to get Context inside DialogInterface.OnClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447092/get-context-inside-onclickdialoginterface-v-int-buttonid)

but none of the answers helped me.

How can I get access to the Activity context inside the `onClick()` method of `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` (without using Activity.this) ?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to access the parent activity from within the `AlertDialog`'s `onClick()` method but did not want to maintain an activity reference because my `AlertDialog`'s `onClick()` handler is in another file.  For API 23 and newer, this is what worked for me:

In the activity where AlertDialog.Builder is called I added this:

```
dialog.setOwnerActivity(this);
dialog.show();
.....
```

I then pass my builder to another class. So in this separate class which implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
        Dialog dialog  = (Dialog) dialogInterface;
        Activity activity = dialog.getOwnerActivity();
        // do some work with activity
    }
};
```

This will work with all of the DialogInterface listeners.

Acknowledgement goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22049950/923920) by @petey for pointing me in the right direction.