# How to call startActivity from an internal anonymous class of an ArrayAdapter class?

Tags: android, android-intent

Sorry, this is my first question...
I have an *ArrayAdapter* class and i want to call *startActivity* from an internal anonymous class, but i'm taking the error "cannot resolve method startActivity"

```
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable final View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    //inflating the layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemview_antliostasia, parent, false);

    //get the reference to the view objects
    final TextView myName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.itemViewAntliostasiaName);
    final TextView myID = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.itemViewAntliostasiaID);
    final TextView myAntlies = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.itemViewAntliostasiaAntlies);
    ImageView myEdit = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageAntliostasiaEdit);
    ImageView myDelete = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageAntliostasiaDelete);

    //providing the element of an ArrayList by specifying its position
    myName.setText(dataList.get(position).getName());
    myID.setText(dataList.get(position).getId());
    myAntlies.setText(dataList.get(position).getAntlies());
    myEdit.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgedit);
    myDelete.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgdelete);

    myEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public  void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EditAntliostasioActivity.class);
            String[] editValues = new String[2];
            editValues[0] = myName.getText().toString();
            editValues[1] = myAntlies.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("edit values", editValues);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

I think something is going wrong with getContext()...Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get context inside onClick(DialogInterface v, int buttonId)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447092/get-context-inside-onclickdialoginterface-v-int-buttonid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startActivity()` is a method of `Context` so you need to call it on the `Context` object:

```
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Note that if the `Context` was not an `Activity`, then you would need also to set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` on the `Intent`. But `startActivity()` is overridden in `Activity` to not need that, and you have an activity context here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), EditAntliostasioActivity.class);
```

The reason for this error was because the `getContext()` was returning the context of the activity instead of the anonymous class. Hence, you have to use `view.getContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance variables of Context..

```
Class Vehicle
{
Context mContext;
```

Initialize Context...

```
public Vehicle(Context mContext)
{
this.mContext = mContext;
}
```

Whenever you are calling startActivity do like this..in your case..

```
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```